# I am creating a custom widget "SPONSORED BEST SELLER PRODUCTS" block to show on home page. Bestseller.phtml file not rendering in the front end

Tags: magento2, custom, widget, widgets, recently-viewed

> ### This is my registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
     \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
     'Relabs_LabAPI',
     __DIR__
    );
```

> ### This is my module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Relabs_LabAPI" setup_version="1.0.2" schema_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_CatalogWidget"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> ### This is my widget.xml

```
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/widget.xsd">
    <widget id="sponsored_bestsellerwidget" class="Relabs\LabAPI\Block\Widget\Bestseller">
        <label translate="true">Bestseller</label>
        <description>Widget in Magento2</description>
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="title" xsi:type="text" required="false" visible="true">
                <label>Title</label>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="description" xsi:type="text" required="false" visible="true">
                <label>Description</label>
            </parameter>
        </parameters>
    </widget>

</widgets>
```

> ### This is my Bestseller.php

```
<?php

namespace Relabs\LabAPI\Block\Widget;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use \Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface;

class Bestseller extends \Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList  {
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('widget/Bestseller.phtml');
    }
    public function createCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
            ->setPageSize(2) // only get 2 products 
            ->setCurPage(1)  // first page (means limit 0,10)
            ->load(); 
        return $collection->getData();
    }


}
```

> Till here everything is working fine.
>   when I am printing $collection, below is the output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 1
            [attribute_set_id] => 15
            [type_id] => simple
            [sku] => 24-MB01
            [has_options] => 0
            [required_options] => 0
            [created_at] => 2018-10-09 06:27:13
            [updated_at] => 2018-10-09 06:27:13
            [price] => 34.0000
            [tax_class_id] => 2
            [final_price] => 34.0000
            [minimal_price] => 34.0000
            [min_price] => 34.0000
            [max_price] => 34.0000
            [tier_price] => 
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [entity_id] => 2
        [attribute_set_id] => 15
        [type_id] => simple
        [sku] => 24-MB04
        [has_options] => 0
        [required_options] => 0
        [created_at] => 2018-10-09 06:27:13
        [updated_at] => 2018-10-09 06:27:13
        [price] => 32.0000
        [tax_class_id] => 2
        [final_price] => 32.0000
        [minimal_price] => 32.0000
        [min_price] => 32.0000
        [max_price] => 32.0000
        [tier_price] => 
        )

)
```

> ### This is my widget template(Bestseller.phtml)

```
<?php
  $blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('RecoSense\LabAPI\Block\Widget\Bestseller');
  $blockObj->createCollection();
?>
```

> What should I do here so that it can use existing theme block 
>   like "RECENTLY VIEWED ITEMS". I dont want to create custom 
>   html templates, I want to use the theme block template. 
>   Please suggest ???